# What was Carter's actual fate?

Tags: final-destination

What was Carter's actual fate ?

> Was carter really the next one to die?

In the scene where Alex, Clear, Billy and Carter are together in the car, because they believe

> Alex knows who's next to die

, Alex is all quiet as though

> Carter really is next

But was it really so, or was

> Carter jumping to conclusions?

This is the one

> death that wasn't really explicit in terms of who was destined for it

I know

> Carter dies in the end

but still